# Display images in HTML + Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to nodejs. I want to create a very simple website which has 3 pages. In every page I want to display an image to make the pages look uniform.

My code looks like this:

```
    /**
     * Module dependencies.
     */

    var express = require('express');
    var routes = require('./routes');
    var user = require('./routes/user');
    var http = require('http');
    var path = require('path');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var mail = require("nodemailer").mail;

/*List of variables*/

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/main', function(req, res) {

    fs.readFile('./home.html', function(error, content) {
        if (error) {
            res.writeHead(500);
            res.end();
        }
        else {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            res.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    });

});

/* After this I have code for post event - all these navigation works perfectly fine*/
```

in `home.html` file I have an image to display:

```
/*Header part of HTML file*/

<body>

        <img class="logo" src="./Heading.png" alt="My_Logo">
        console.log (src);
        <h1 class="center">Welcome to message reprocessing</h1>
    </br>
</body>
```

This image is not displayed in my browser. When I check my console I have this error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/Heading.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: The console.log(...) statement won't quite work that way... You can't just add javascript to html. It has to be in a <script></script> tag and has to be executed in some way.
Also, could you post your directory layout here? Are you sure you have Heading.png in your public directory?

Comment: Is the `Heading.png` located at the same folder as `home.html` is?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.I had tried using absolute path already with no luck. However one of my friend suggested as below:

```
<img class="logo" src="http://localhost:3000/images/Heading.png" alt="My_Logo">
```

and keep the `Heading.png` file in `public/images` directory.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 24):

First, you have to set the public (folder) as static under server.js file

```
server.js

// configure our application
const Express = require('express');
const app = new Express();
.......
.......
app.use(Express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
.......
```

then your img source will be

```
<img class="logo" src="/images/Heading.png" alt="My_Logo">
```

and here the folders structure would be -

```
 project(root folder) \ public \ images\ Heading.png
```

Answer (score 8):

Okay, its not with express.js, but here is a snippet of my code that handles images and external javascripts, but has a protection:

```
function handler (req, res){
var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
var isImage = 0, contentType, fileToLoad;
var extension = pathname.split('.').pop();
var file = "." + pathname;
var dirs = pathname.split('/');
if(pathname == "/"){
    file = "index.html";
    contentType = 'text/html';
    isImage = 2;
}
else if(dirs[1] != "hidden" && pathname != "/app.js"){
    switch(extension){
        case "jpg":
            contentType = 'image/jpg';
            isImage = 1;
            break;
        case "png":
            contentType = 'image/png';
            isImage = 1;
            break;
        case "js":
            contentType = 'text/javascript';
            isImage = 2;
            break;
        case "css":
            contentType = 'text/css';
            isImage = 2;
            break;
        case "html":
            contentType = 'text/html';
            isImage = 2;
            break;
    }
}
if(isImage == 1){
    fileToLoad = fs.readFileSync(file);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':  contentType });
    res.end(fileToLoad, 'binary');
}
else if(isImage == 2){
    fileToLoad = fs.readFileSync(file, "utf8");
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':  contentType });
    res.write(fileToLoad);
    res.end();
}
```

This assuming that you have your app.js and index.html in your root, you can have folders like /css, /img, /js etc. But the app.js and content inside your /hidden folder is unable to reach, but files in your root is still accessable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a quick solution, do this: instead of this `<img class="logo" src="./Heading.png" alt="My_Logo">` use:

```
<img class="logo" src="your file path /Heading.png" alt="My_Logo">
```

Still not working? 
check image spelling, file extension(png) because png and PNG are different in live server(case sensitive). 
and verify

```
path.join(__dirname, 'public')
```

too

Comment: it would be nice if you could specify what "your file path" represents using an example 
is it local host base url or just a path , this would help others

Comment: @NelsonBwogora — Why not check it from your directory?

Answer (score 1):

Index.js
Inside this file, add the code below to give the directory name to your index.js (server), in a way it is based on your actual directory path.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));
```

**Directory Structure**

[image]

now inside Index.ejs (you HTML page) add the code below to insert your image and make it visible.

```
<div id="main-content">
  <img src="img\navthome" />
</div>
```

Notice inside IMG tag we set the SRC as "img\navthome.gif", here we don't need to declare all the path since we already declared the __dirname, and the PUBLIC folder inside index.js

I hope it can helps you with your issue :D

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems I had was that I wanted to define a few specific paths and I found the best answer in the link below.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fetch-images-from-node-js-server/

```
// Requiring module
const express = require('express');
 
// Creating express object
const app = express();

// Defining port number
const PORT = 3000;                 

// Function to serve all static files
// inside public directory.
app.use(express.static('public')); 
app.use('/images', express.static('images'));
 
// Server setup
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Running server on PORT ${PORT}...`);
})
```

I did the following in my program:

Shows the structure of folders and files here

```
 root
   > client
   > node_modules
   > folder_1
   > folder_2
   > package.json
   > server.js
```

And on my server I define that folder_1 in fl1 path and folder_2 in fl2 path each have a separate static path. And the interesting thing is that I do not use the original name of those folders and I give it my own route.

```
 // Requiring module
 const express = require('express');
 const path = require('path');

 // Creating express object
 const app = express();

 // http://localhost:3000/fl1/...
 app.use('/fl1',express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,'folder_1')));

 // http://localhost:3000/fl2/...
 app.use('/fl2',express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,'folder_2')));

 // Server setup
 app.listen(3000, () => {
   console.log(`Running server on port 3000`);
 })
```

After running the server to access this path is enough to use the following path to access its contents.

> Note that you must specify the internal routes accurately. For example, the subfolders and file name must be specified. main path `/folder_1/img/image_1.png` in url `/fl1/img/image.png`.